# create expression designer in java

Tags: java, user-interface, designer

I'm trying to create a expression designer in Java, any idea if there are something like that in the market? The expression that i need to build are like this:

1. Var >= 5 Or Var = null
2. Var2 > 20 And Var2 < 50
3. Var3 = 15

How can i do this?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you referring to a rules engine for product design?

Comment: The idea is to create something like query designer, that allows me to create dynamic condition (where condition) inside a query.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you need?

```
if (Var >= 5 || var == null)
  if (Var2 > 20 && Var2<50)
     Var3 = 15;
```

Answer (score 0):

I doubt there is any out-of-the-box tool that lets you define your own expression language (or do you have a specific language in mind?) and provides you a generic GUI for that.

Comment: Hi michael667, just arithmetic expression

Comment: Yeah, but that is only common sense, not a definition. Which operators do you want to support? Which functions? etc.

Comment: The same operators inside a sql where condition =, <>, <=, >=, <, >